Is there something like @Embeddable for Hibernate in Diesel for Rust
I have the following structs
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Queryable, Selectable)]
#[diesel(table_name = crate::schema::parents)]
#[diesel(check_for_backend(diesel::pg::Pg))]
pub struct Parent {
  id: i32,
  surname: String,
  child: Child
}

pub struct Child {
  name: String,
  age: u8,
}

And I want to have the following schema.rs
diesel::table! {
    parents (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        surname -> Text,
        name -> Text,
        age -> Int4,
    }
}

But I can't make it work, and I was wondering whether is possible to have embeddable structs in Diesel?

I don't think you can #[derive(Queryable, Selectable)], but you can always implement them yourself.

Pretty sure you can put #[diesel(embed)] on child: Child (and add the derives to Child). I'll try to verify later.
